# Echo canceling on a Samsung Tab S7

Tags: android, audio

I am having some issues in activating echo canceling on an Android samsung tablet running android 11.

The software needs to listen to the microphone, while ignoring the output from the speakers.
I tried using the AudioManager to create an AcousticEchoCanceler

```
        audioManager.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION
        audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn = true

        audioRecord = AudioRecord.Builder()
            .setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION)
            .build()

        if (AcousticEchoCanceler.isAvailable()){
            acousticCanceler = AcousticEchoCanceler.create(audioRecord.audioSessionId)
            acousticCanceler.enabled = true           
        }
```

I also tried using WebRtcAudioUtils to enable software AEC while disabling the hardware one without success so far.

```
    WebRtcAudioUtils.setWebRtcBasedAcousticEchoCanceler(true)
    WebRtcAudioUtils.setWebRtcBasedAutomaticGainControl(true)
    WebRtcAudioUtils.setWebRtcBasedNoiseSuppressor(true);


    JavaAudioDeviceModule.builder(this)
        .setUseHardwareAcousticEchoCanceler(false)
        .setUseHardwareNoiseSuppressor(false)
        .setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION)
        .createAudioDeviceModule()
```

Any help or hints would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this specific device. I use the hardware AEC with WebRtc.

```
    // Telling  audio manager
    // that the speakers are on.
    audioManager.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION
    audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn = true

    // Enabling hardware acoustic echo canceler
    val a = JavaAudioDeviceModule.builder(this)
        .setUseHardwareAcousticEchoCanceler(true)
        .setUseHardwareNoiseSuppressor(true)
        .setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION)
        .createAudioDeviceModule()

    // Disabling software echo canceler
    WebRtcAudioUtils.setWebRtcBasedAcousticEchoCanceler(false)
    WebRtcAudioUtils.setWebRtcBasedNoiseSuppressor(false);
```